# Increasing current

Tags: power, constant-current

Here an interesting challenge. You have a 3 volt 50uAh battery. How many would it take to create a device that can supply 3 volts at 1mAH. Would you connect them in parallel or series or a series/parallel combination?

Comment: Not a challenge. A very straightforward application of KCL.

Comment: Try dividing 1000 by 50 as a lower limit.

Comment: Start by rewriting the values in same units. 3V is 3V that is easy, but how many μAh are there in a mAh?

Comment: are you talking about battery capacities here (in Ah) or current (in A)? with 'Supply 3 volts at 1mAH' do you mean 'create a 3V, 1mAh battery'?

Comment: At a minimum, this question is confusing "current" (A) with "capacity" (Ah at implied V).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a regulated 3V supply, I'd put 25 or 30 in series and use high voltage buck regulator (eg. LM5009) with discontinuous mode to produce a well-regulated 3V supply.

If it's not a regulated 3V supply, it kinda sounds like a homework problem that you could benefit more from doing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am reading the question incorrectly, but it looks like you would simply put 20 of the 3 volt 50uAh batteries in parallel and that would give you a battery that is 3 volts and 1mAh.

Putting batteries together in parallel keeps the voltage the same, but adds the amperage or current.(Assuming all batteries are of the same voltage rating)

Putting batteries together in series keeps the amperage or current the same and adds the voltage (assuming all batteries are of the same amperage rating)